# How do I bind a card to a button in Angular when there are multiple cards fetching data from database

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am making a blogpost app using Angular and REST service. I need to have an edit and delete functionality in the application and this is what I have done for it

Component Code :

```
export class EditblogsComponent implements OnInit {
    allBlogs: any;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/blogPosts').subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.allBlogs = data as string[];
            },
            (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        );
    }

    editBlog() {}
    deleteBlog() {}
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">

            <div class="card border-primary" *ngFor="let blog of allBlogs">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-title">
                        <h1>
                            {{blog.blogTitle}}
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-text text-left">
                        {{blog.blogContent}}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <footer class="blockquote-footer">
                    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0 text-end">
                        Written by : {{blog.blogUser}}
                    </blockquote>
                </footer>

                <div class="row button-row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editBlog()">Edit
                            blog</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteBlog()">Delete
                            blog</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

JSON Server for the blog section:

```
"blogPosts": [
    {
        "blogUser": "usera",
        "blogTitle": "Title for first blogppost",
        "blogContent": "Content of first blogpost",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "blogUser": "usera",
        "blogTitle": "Title for second blogppost",
        "blogContent": "Content of second blogpost",
        "id": 2
    }
],
```

I want to know how I can bind the edit and delete buttons so that they work on the specific blog that renders in the cards.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the blog or it's id as an argument to the functions.

html

```
<div class="row button-row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editBlog(blog)">Edit
                            blog</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteBlog(blog.id)">Delete
                            blog</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

component

```
editBlog(blog: Blog) {}
    deleteBlog(blogId: number) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the specific 'blog' object as an argument to the edit and delete methods like so:

HTML:

```html
 <div class="row button-row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="editBlog(blog)">Edit
                            blog</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteBlog(blog)">Delete
                            blog</button>
                    </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
editBlog(blog:any) 
{
}
deleteBlog(blog:any) 
{
}
```